# how can you check if url has parameter html

Tags: html, razor

So there is some issue, I am trying to do if-else statement in HTML to figure out if URL has parameter/string

I have var **url**  and I need to check if that URL has parametr

prbly i did not explain it clearly, I need to check if website itself has string. So when you open some website and it should check if it has some word in there

```
                        <div class="url-check" style="@style">
                            @if (url != null)
                            {
                                <a href="@url" target="_blank">@text</a>
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                <p>@text</p>
                            }
                        </div>
```

I tried something like **if(url.inculdes('something'))** but it does not work, so how can I make it works

Comment: HTML is markup language, it has no if-else statements. What other technologies are you using? You can do the URL check on both server-side and/or client-side...

Comment: I am doing it in MVS and using cshtml

Answer (score 0):

Select a tag using one of javascript dom selectors. and then use getAttribute('url') on that element. Then you will just have to do a simple if statement if the value is equal to null.

Comment: how can you make it, so it will work in MVS using cshtml

Answer (score 0):

You can use AlpineJs in your HTML

see this page: (https://alpinejs.dev/)

```
<div x-data="{ open: false }">
    <template x-if="open">
        <div>...</div>
    </template>
</div>
```

Comment: I need to do it auto, like when page is open it should read that without pressing any btn

Comment: read docs Alpine. It is very fast and uses javascript. You can use JavaScript by Alpine without much knowledge

Comment: prbly i did not explain it clearly, I need to check if website itself has string. So when you open some website and it should check if it has some word in there